# Problem in showing multiple data count results in one page with different condition in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using livewire and I want to display some data count results based on their respective conditions..

However, the view page only shows 1 result of count, which should be 4. [Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD9Xm.png)..

And here's the line of code in the livewire render component:

```
$prospek = Prospek::orderby('prospek.id', 'desc');
     
        if($this->status == 'baru')
        {
            $prospek = $prospek->where('status_donor', $this->status);
            $data ['ket'] = "Prospek";
        } 
        
        if($this->status == 'donatur')
        {
            $prospek = $prospek->where('status_donor', $this->status);
            $data ['ket'] = "Donatur";
        } 
        
        if($this->status == 'nonaktif')
        {
            $prospek = $prospek->where('status_donor', $this->status);
            $data ['ket'] = "Non Aktif";
        }
        
        if($this->status == 'hapus')
        {
            $prospek = $prospek->where('status_donor', $this->status);
            $data ['ket'] = "Dihapus";
        }

        if($this->cariNama != null ){
            $prospek = $prospek->where('nama','LIKE', '%'.$this->cariNama.'%');
        }
        
        if($this->cariHp != null ){
            $prospek = $prospek->where('hp', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->cariHp.'%');
        }

        $data ['prospek'] = $prospek->paginate($this->jumlahBaris);

        $data ['jmlBaru'] = $prospek->where('status_donor', 'baru')->count();
        $data ['jmlDonatur'] = $prospek->where('status_donor', 'donatur')->count();
        $data ['jmlNonAktif'] = $prospek->where('status_donor', 'nonaktif')->count();
        $data ['jmlHapus'] = $prospek->where('status_donor', 'hapus')->count();

        return view('livewire.donatur.tabel-donatur', $data);
```

And here's the code line in blade file:

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" wire:click="status(0)" data-toggle="tab"
        href="#donatur">
        Prospek {{ number_format($jmlBaru, 0, ',', '.') }}</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" wire:click="status(1)" data-toggle="tab"
        href="#donatur">
        Donatur {{ number_format($jmlDonatur, 0, ',', '.') }}</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" wire:click="status(2)" data-toggle="tab"
        href="#donatur">
        Non Aktif {{ number_format($jmlNonAktif, 0, ',', '.') }}</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" wire:click="status(3)" data-toggle="tab"
        href="#donatur">
        Dihapus {{ number_format($jmlHapus, 0, ',', '.') }}</button>
```

Can anyone show me how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Livewire but purely to Laravel and the way you're utilizing the query builder.

On your first line, you set the query:
`$prospek = Prospek::orderby('prospek.id', 'desc');`.
Then, with each if statement, you add conditions to the query. Then, at last, you want to get the count of each different status.

However, you're adding conditions to the query *before* you fetch the count. If you were to dump the query (`\DB::enableQueryLog()` before starting your query, `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after finishing the last query) you would see that each condition has been added. Basically, your `jmlHapus` will be a `Prospek` that has to have each of the 4 queried statuses (which will never happen if I see your code).

Instead, what you can do is the following:

```php
$counts = $prospek->selectRaw('status_donor, COUNT(*) as count')
    ->groupBy('status_donor')
    ->pluck('count', 'status_donor');
```

Now `$counts` will be a collection where each key is the status and the values are the counts.

Then, you can simply set your values like so:

```php
$data['jmlBaru'] = $counts['baru'] ?? 0;
$data['jmlDonatur'] = $counts['donatur'] ?? 0;
$data['jmlNonAktif'] = $counts['nonaktif'] ?? 0;
$data['jmlHapus'] = $counts['hapus'] ?? 0;
```

I personally would suggest making this more dynamic, but for now this should get your counts working.

Comment: thx for your suggestion..
I tried it, and it works..